# Enable disable records for each row in Interactive report oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I have a interactive grid and one item p11_active_yn , based on the item value i want to check this condition for each row , in one grid we may have so many records, the enable disable should check and do for each row in interactive grid,, how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Allowed Row Operations" attribute of the Interactive Grid. That feature meets your requirement. The help text is pretty clear.

Let me give an example:

This is on the EMP/DEPT sample dataset. There is page item P72_JOB. Only for the selected job, the record is editable.

Source Query:

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO,
       CASE JOB WHEN :P72_JOB THEN 'U' ELSE NULL END AS UPDATE_ALLOWED
  from EMP
```

Items to submit: P72_JOB

IG Attribute: Allowed Row Operations column: UPDATE_ALLOWED

For the test I added a dynamic action on P72_JOB to refresh the interactive grid on change. Now the interactive grid only allows the rows to be edited for the selected job.

Comment: "CASE JOB WHEN :P72_JOB THEN 'U' ELSE NULL END AS UPDATE_ALLOWED" its lil confused,
here my item p11_active_yn  will have Y , N default N will be there.. if its N then disable if the user changes this to Y then enable i need like this your example is lil confused

Comment: whats JOB in your example , if its an column then how you are comparing like "case job when P72_JOB", in my items i have oly 2 values Y or N

Comment: In my case P72_JOB is a select list with the jobs in the emp table. It should be trivial to change that to Y/N for your business case. I just wanted to show a generic example of how to use the row operations feature.